# column bind in loop in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have this loop (see below). I also have a dataframe called `want.result`. what I get from this loop (alist) is a list of three columns that I need to cbind with `want.result`(same size as columns in the list) with column names of respective item of `all.bam.files`. I tried something that's commented out, but doesn't seem to work. What do I need to add in this loop to get this done?

```
   alist<-{}
    for(i in 1:length(all.bam.files)){
      alist[[i]] = cc(all.bam.files[i],mydf)
      #temp<-cbind(want.result, all.bam.files[i]=alist[i])
      #ccc <-rbind(ccc, temp)    
 }
```

Comment: What is `cc()` - that is not a function is it?

Comment: what does it do?  also, `alist` is a base function

Comment: list has same number of columns as there are files in all.bam.files. I need to append those columns in the want.result dataframe (of equal row numbers) pasting the respective all.bam.file name as column name.

Comment: what is `alist` supposed to be?  currently you assign it the value of an empty expression, which is NULL.  The you use a function `cc` that isnt defined anywhere.

Comment: cc takes each individual file in all.bam.files list and a mydf dataframe which then stores all the output in the alist(basically they are the wanted columns) as output from each individual file in all.bam.files list. I need to column bind unlisted alist to want.result dataframe pasting the respective all.bam.files names as column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem well, you can do all this without a for loop:

```
# Call cc() with each element of all.bam.files as 1st argument 
# and mydf as 2nd argument. Combine results in a list.
alist <- lapply(all.bam.files, cc, mydf) 

# Name each element to alist using the corresponding element of all.bam.files
names(alist) <- all.bam.files

# cbind want.result with all elements in the list alist
temp <- do.call(cbind, c(want.result, alist))
```